# Docker not completely removed

Tags: docker, centos

I have a problem while installing `docker-ce`

I trying to remove old docker by using command `yum remove docker docker-common docker-selinux docker-engine`. But I noticed that **all** docker command is still usable.
For example,

`[root@caffeDNN ~]# docker version 
Client: Version: 1.13.1 
API version: 1.26 
Go version: go1.7.5 
Git commit: 092cba3 
Built: Wed Feb 8 08:47:51 2017 
OS/Arch: linux/amd64 
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? 
[root@caffeDNN ~]#`

So, I trying to uninstall it again by using the same command but yum could not found any docker package anymore.

Is there any solution to remove `docker` completely by avoiding conflict with `docker-ce`?

Method I tried

Answer (score 47, accepted):

##### A) To uninstall `Docker Engine`:

```
sudo yum remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

##### B) To uninstall old versions of docker (previously called `docker` or `docker-engine`):

```
sudo yum remove docker \
              docker-client \
              docker-client-latest \
              docker-common \
              docker-latest \
              docker-latest-logrotate \
              docker-logrotate \
              docker-engine
```

---

And delete

- the directories `/var/lib/docker` and/or `/var/lib/containerd`, which contains your images, containers and volumes
- and `/etc/docker`, which contains docker configuration files.

Source: [Official docs (uninstall Docker Engine)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#uninstall-docker-engine) | [Official docs (uninstall old versions)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#uninstall-old-versions).

Comment: Hello, sorry for delay response. I just tried that but no luck. Let me explain.
https://gist.github.com/rayriffy/ed7646383fdc72f79170f04064fb9118
From this gist, you can clearly see that yum is removed docker 1.12 but what happened from there I executed `docker --version` and Docker responded that he's on version 1.13.1. Wired

Comment: Next, I ignore this problem and replacing with `docker-ce` by installing via rpm packages (because I have a problem with SSL handshake with docker-ce repo) and I try `docker --version` again and... he's still responding 1.13.1.

Comment: After you have uninstalled try ``yum list installed | grep docker`` and ``which docker`` to get the location of the executable. Consider to remove the file printed out by ``which`` and try installing it again. If it still prints out the old version even on reinstall: scan/search your disk for something like ``*docker*`` and inspect those files and file locations. Are you installing the latest version?

Answer (score 41):

for newer versions you need to remove the cli as well

```sh
sudo yum remove -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli
```

that will do the trick

Comment: This saved me from going extra mile to waste everything. thanks!

Comment: What about `containerd.io` ?

Comment: Thank you. This saved me when doing a downgrade of Docker...

Answer (score 6):

A newer answer for this is:

Uninstall the Docker Engine, CLI, and Containerd packages:

```
$ sudo yum remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Images, containers, volumes, or customized configuration files on your host are not automatically removed. To delete all images, containers, and volumes:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#uninstall-docker-engine

Answer (score 3):

I'm on CentOS 7 and followed all the above suggestions which worked to remove docker's files and commands, but I still found it in my repo list.

```
yum repolist
```

Showed up...

```
docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64            Docker CE Stable - x86_64                             117
```

I removed it via the following commands:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
rm docker-ce.repo
rm: remove regular file ‘docker-ce.repo’? y
```

This removed it then I ran these two commands  (add sudo before each if you are not logged in as root) to clean the cache and update:

```
yum clean all
yum makecache
```

I then found 2 further entries in the yum cache that needed removing manually:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/docker-ce-nightly
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/docker-ce-stable
```